# How to set graph's lines to appear in parallel in Grafana

Tags: grafana

I'm setting a line graph in Grafana (DB-influx) with multiple lines. Each line can be presented separately or all the lines together.
(This behavior can be tested in https://play.grafana.org/d/000000002/influxdb-templated?orgId=1)

I couldn't find the option that will allow presenting any chosen combination of lines.
The required presentation can be seen in this movie sec 0:23 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUvJamHeMpw

Thanks